# Servlet add dynamically?

Tags: http, servlets, dynamically-generated

I have the following request:

I want to creat with follow request(POST)

```
localhost:8080/Anwendung/bla?createServlet=machine&input=2&name&state
```

a new „request possibility“  After i executed the above URL i can add with follow POST

```
localhost:8080/Anwendung/machine?name =&state=off
```

a new machine in a database. Now i can get with a GET request:

```
localhost:8080/Anwendung/machine?name
```

the machine as JSON File.

My first idea is that i make for every „request possibility“  a new servlet, which i add dynamically at the runtime. After i made the above example i have „machine.java“, which i compiling and add(hot deployment(??)) in my server(tomcat).
It es possible? 
I think there is a better possibility